# Remove "0's" from column

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, divide

How can I adjust this formula to remove the repeating "0's" when the cell is empty. I want it to include any cell that has a number, even 0, but exclude cells that are empty.

```
=ArrayFormula({"Price"; query(value(Misc.!H2:H19), "where Col1 is not null",)})

=ArrayFormula({"Price"; query(value(Misc.!H2:H19), "where Col1 <> 0",)})
```

Tried both of these with no luck. I'm sure I'm missing something very minor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just wondering why you need value - is it because some of the numbers are stored as strings? The issue is that value will turn the blanks into zeroes so you can't test them for being blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divide by 1 and again by 1 to force an error and then hide it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Price"; IFERROR(1/(1/(VALUE(Misc.!H2:H19))))})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Price"; IF(A2:A="",,VALUE(Misc.!H2:H19))})
```

Comment: when I use that formula all cells in the column are blank

Comment: @cpaone can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I just tried, but it is referencing a bunch of other sheets and it doesn't show anything when I make a copy.